# Wrong Python interpreter being used by VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and have both `Python2` and `Python3` installed natively. I have also installed Python through `miniforge`, a variant of `miniconda`. In `VSCode` I have both the `MS Python extension` and `Pylance` installed.

I use the `miniforge` python for my coding. This works perfectly fine in `PyCharm`.

However in `VSCode`, when I try to execute the same file I get errors. After investigating it seems that `VSCode` is picking native `Python2` - even though I have the `miniforge` Python selected. In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFsS2.jpg) it can be seen that the status bar at the bottom states `Python interpreter` selected is Python3. But the output window shows that the python interpreter is Python2.

A more confusing thing is when I use VSCode for Jupyter notebook files then it picks up the interpreter correctly and I have no issues.

I have checked both User and Workspace settings, and they all point to Python3. How can I fix this for standard .py files?

I prefer VSCode to PyCharm, but will need to use PyCharm till this is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your system console cannot see python3. You need to put the python3 in the PATH variable, *before* python2. Like:

```
PATH=path/to/python3:path/to/python2:$PATH
```

Also, make sure that the environment containing python3 is activated before command prompt appears. It can be done in `bash_profile` by adding a line like

```
conda activate my_env_with_python3
```

Try changing the settings "Python:Python path", "Python:default interpreter path" and "Python:conda path" also.

Comment: On system using the python command gets me Python3. To get Python2 I have to run python2. Also, VSCode does pick up the miniforge/conda environment - when I run the python terminal by itself or work with a jupyter notebook, all of it executes within the conda environment. Its only when running a .py file by itself that I get this error.

Comment: I have updated all these 3 paths, but it didn't change anything.I also activated Conda and ran VSCode from the commandline, but it is still picking up Python2.

Comment: Is there a .vscode folder near this file which might be overriding the settings ?

Comment: I've run out of ideas.. please file a bug report https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: I ultimately nuked the problem by removing Python2 from my system. Now VSCode picks the interpreter as per the settings. It uses the python in the Conda install, not the system python3. Now am finding and fixing/reinstalling apps that needed python2. Thanks for the feedback. I will try to file a bug report, but might be difficult since I can no longer reproduce the issuel.

Answer (score 0):

I have just bumped into something similar. The `Run code` option resulted in the file being run with the default interpreter instead of the venv-based one with necessary packages installed.

**The fix was simply to use "Run python file" instead:**

[image]

The run-code behavior must be customizable, something is mentioned e.g. here: [Run Code vs Run Python File in Terminal for VSCODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753702/run-code-vs-run-python-file-in-terminal-for-vscode) but I didn't bother.