# Run Code vs Run Python File in Terminal for VSCODE

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I seem to be stuck with trying to run python3 files in vscode. I have noticed the Triangle button in the top right hand side to run code is no longer coloured green too.

I have set up my own venv for python3 and have installed the numpy package - I've checked `pip list` and it's there and runs fine when called any methods from this package upon importing it.

When i right click the file in vscode and click on *Run Python File in Terminal* - it runs perfectly fine and gives me the desired outputs.

However, when I click *Run Code* or *Alt+shift+N* it opens up the *Output* tab next to the terminal and produces no output - just an error message stating that the module numpy does not exist.

I do not understand this, since the numpy pacakge is installed. Can anyone try and help me with this - because it is quite tiring having the right click all the time and click "run python file in the terminal" i was hoping for a keyboard shortcut instead.

I've attached my code below

```
import numpy as np 
print(np.round(5/30,decimals=3))
```

Please see the following screen captures.

You can clearly see the output running correctly in when Python3 file is sent to the terminal - but in the OUTPUT tab it's an error!

[image: Works in Terminal]

The above is the correct result from the Terminal

Below is the result of the OUTPUT tab.

[image: Fails when running in OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself - the answer was simply here:

[How to execute Python code from within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987840/how-to-execute-python-code-from-within-visual-studio-code)

I needed to change the path of the code-runner in the settings.json file as that was activated.